# Add more labels to a UIStackView programmatically

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a UIStackView that contains one Label. I want to display a list of Labels (badges) in the UIStackView. On the first badge, I update the first label and on the other badges, I copy the first badge and add it to the UIStackView with addSubview.  It seems to be working but it only shows the last item instead of showing all.

My idea was to have the first Label in the stack view done within the Storyboard so I can easily style it and then clone it in code.  Not sure if this is a good approach.

```
import UIKit

class SessionFullResultViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var badgesStackView: UIStackView!
    @IBOutlet weak var badge1: UILabel!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {

        ...
        ...

        new_badges.enumerated().forEach { (index, badge) in
            if (index == 0) {
                self.badge1.text = badge.info
            }
            else {
                var newbadge = self.badge1
                newbadge?.text = badge.name
                self.badgesStackView.addSubview(newbadge!)
            }
            
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't believe you are actually copying when you go `var newbade = self.bade1`. You need to make `UILabel` copy-able and create an actual copy. Not 100% sure this will fix the issue, but maybe a start. To check this you could simply just do `else { var newLabel = UILabel(frame: badge1.frame) newLabel.text = "ABRACADABRA" self.stackview.addsubview(newLabel) }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new instance of a label for every text you want to insert, as impression7vx suggested, and also use the `addArrangedSubview` method

Try to change your code to

```
new_badges.enumerated().forEach { (index, badge) in
            if (index == 0) {
                self.badge1.text = badge.info
            } else {
                var newbadge = UILabel(frame: badge1.frame)
                newbadge.text = badge.name
                self.badgesStackView.addArrangedSubview(newbadge)
            }

            // Refresh the stack view at the end
            if index == new_badges.count - 1 {
                self.badgesStackView.layoutIfNeeded()
            }
        }
```

I don't know what kind of layout you want to get, but, with a dynamic list of elements
it's usually better to use a `UITableView`.